# Wordpress get user role with php

Tags: php, wordpress, user-roles

I'm creating a page in my wordpress site, with a list of the users and need to get the title of their role with php. But, every thing I tried failed. Anyone who can help please.

Comment: Can you be more specific? What exactly have you tried and what problems did you run into while trying.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function that returns the current user roles :

```
function display_user_roles(){
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    $user_info = get_userdata( $user_id );
    $user_roles = implode(', ', $user_info->roles);
    return $user_roles;
}
```

To use it in your code:

```
<?php echo display_user_roles(); ?>
```